# Leagues not changed from Feb to March

Tags: support

This is already March but the link in my profile ( which shows top x.x% this month) is still pointing to February.
It say that time will be counted on UTC.
But in UTC, time is

```js
console.log(new Date().toUTCString());
```

Why it is not yet changed to March?

Answer (score 6):

> Why it is not yet changed to March?

Because leagues are always updated to *yesterday*.

You will notice that the UTC date is still March 1st, not March 2nd.

Answer (score 5):

Leagues count the points scored each day (as well as other periods). We don't know what your score will be for today till the end of the day. So the system has to be 1 day behind as it only updates daily.